# How to get button to change visibility based on checkbox in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, event-listener

new to JS here and working on a react project, I want to essentially have the button's visibility attribute which is set to false to change to true when a checkbox is checked, here is my code and I believe the logic is there but for some reason is not reflected on the UI, any advice is appreciated

```
    const [visible, setVisibility] = useState(false)

    function clicked() {
        console.log('in cliked')
        const check = document.getElementById('acknowledged')
        check.addEventListener('click', showContinueButton())
        setVisibility(true)
    }


    function showContinueButton() {
        
        const continueButton = document.getElementById('continue')

        console.log(continueButton.getAttribute("visibility"))
        if(visible) {
            console.log('in the visible for loop')
            continueButton.setAttribute('visibility', 'visible')
        }
        
    }
```

the code above is the code I have defined before the return JSX, then within the JSX I call this code as followed...

`<input type='checkbox' id='acknowledged' onClick={clicked}></input>`

So essentially when this checkbox is clicked, using the onClick attribute, I pass the click function I passed earlier which has an eventListener with a callback function to change the visibility of the button

Comment: why are you using DOM in react???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another variation of what @The KNVB already said:

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

return (
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}/>
        <br />
        { visible && <button>visible button</button> } 
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 3):

With the use of a state, you don't need to manipulate the CSS.

Here is an example for your reference:

```js
const [visible, setVisibility] = useState(false);
let clicked = e => {
  setVisibility(e.target.checked);
}
return ( 
  <div>
     &nbsp; <input type = "checkbox" onClick = {clicked}/> 
     {
      visible &&
      <button> Button1 </button>
     } 
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out that there are a lot of classical JavaScript logic in your functions, which should be used via hooks, and not directly.

Hence these vanilla functions have better alternatives in React.

```js
document.getElementById();
getAttribute();
setAttribute();
```

The right way to resolve your issue should instead be as follows:

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  // 1. the variable 'visible' has initial value equal to false
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  /*
  3. The click handle button updates the state (variable value of visible) to opposite of whatever it is,
  if true , then false, if false, then true
   */
  function onClickHandle() {
    setVisible((visible) => !visible);
  }
  /*
  5. LOGIC
  This function is returned everytime the state of the application changes, meaning everytime a user clicks on the checkbox, the state of var visible changes, and hence the component rerenders.
  */
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label>
        Checkbox
        {/* 2. The input checkbox has a onClick Handler function passed as reference, meaning that function will be called when the checkbox is clicked. */}
        <input type="checkbox" onClick={onClickHandle} />
      </label>
      {/* 4. Application - An example of how to handle the logic, I have used terinary operator but basically it is saying if the value of visible if visible, return 'checked', else return 'not checked' */}
      <h2>Check box is {visible ? "checked" : "not checked"}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Working example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-cookies-v3fz5h?file=/src/App.js:0-439)

Answer (score 0):

```
const [visible, setVisibility] = useState(false)

<button 
  style={{visibility:visible?'visible':'hidden'}}
>
  continue
</button>

<input
  type='checkbox' 
  onClick = {()=>{setVisibility(previousVisibility => !previousVisibility)} 
/>
```